# Displaying the right username in PowerShell command prompt

Tags: windows, powershell, shell, command-line, terminal

When I open PowerShell, I see `Delhivery` as the username in the command prompt.

[image]

I want the PowerShell command prompt to display the username `Hemanta` like so: `PS C:\Users\Hemanta>`.

How can I do that?

Inside my `users` directory, I have the following directories.
[image]
I see a directory called `Delhivery`. Has this anything to do with the user name displayed in the command prompt?

**EDIT-1**

If I go to user accounts in Control Panel, I see the following:
[image]

Comment: Then.. _is_ there a user called `Hemanta` on your computer? Looks like you are loggin in as `Delhivery`, so no surprise if that is the username for the currently logged in user is it?

Comment: Then how can I change the logged in username to `Hemanta`?

Comment: Create a new user called Hemanta or go into your local user management tool as administrator and rename the user Delhivery into Hemanta. Nothing to do with PowerShell, command-line or terminal.

Comment: Please see Edit-1 in the question. When I check user accounts, I have an account with the name `Hemanta Sundaray`. Then why is this name not displayed in the command prompt? Am I missing something?

Comment: That is the `Display Name`, not the `AccountName`

Comment: I clicked on `Change your account name` and changed my account name to `Hemanta`. Yet, I see `Delhivery` in the PowerShell prompt.

Comment: Powershell shows the folder name of the current working folder in the prompt by default. What you want to do makes no sense (this would mean that you would see c:\users\hemanta while you're not at that folder)

Comment: @bluuf I know that. My point is something different. For example in `PS C:\Users\Delhivery\Desktop\mern-auth>` `Delhivery` is the name of the username. I want to change this name. I know that currently I am inside the `mern-auth` directory which is in `Desktop`.

Comment: `Delhivery` is _not_ the user name, it's the name of the user profile folder. [Workarounds exist](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/user-profiles-and-logon/renaming-user-account-not-change-profile-path), but this is not a PowerShell issue

Comment: Check both `$env:USERPROFILE` and `$env:USERNAME`  (see @MathiasR.Jessen's comment).